# Combining Multiple Ranges to Use as Chart Series

Tags: arrays, excel, charts, range, vba

In Excel, I would like to add two dynamic named-ranges together into one range to use in a single-dimension chart series.  The named-ranges are single-dimension and always have matching widths (number of columns).

I created a dynamic array in VBA that combines the named-ranges, but then I learned that Excel charts require static arrays and cannot handle dynamic arrays.

Are there suggestions on how to assign a chart series based on combined dynamic named-ranges?

These are the named-ranges:

```
OFFSET(IncData!$A$1,MATCH("Actual Units"&ReportMetrics!$B$1,IncData!$B:$B&IncData!$A:$A,0)-1,2,,COUNTA(IncData!$1:$1)-2)

OFFSET(IncData!$A$1,MATCH("Remaining Units"&ReportMetrics!$B$1,IncData!$B:$B&IncData!$A:$A,0)-1,2,,COUNTA(IncData!$1:$1)-2)
```

This is the array that I would like use for a chart series:

```
Public Sub CurrentCombinedRemaining()

Dim Dates As Range
Set Dates = Application.Range("IncData!Date")

Dim CurrentRemaining As Range
Dim CurrentActuals As Range
Dim Spread() As Variant

Dim rCount As Integer
rCount = Dates.Count
ReDim Spread(rCount)

Dim i As Integer

Set CurrentRemaining = Application.Range("IncData!CurrentRemaining")
Set CurrentActuals = Application.Range("IncData!CurrentActuals")

For i = 1 To rCount

    Spread(i) = CurrentRemaining.Cells(, i).Value + CurrentActuals.Cells(, i).Value

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post code you already have and what you exactly want to de (using a picture of your Excel Sheet, for example)

Comment: The code has been added.  Thank you.